# Error 1604 while creating table MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a database to model an online courier system.
These are the tables that I am creating.
The error occurs for table `Vehicle`. How can I fix this?

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
cid int(7) NOT NULL,
cfname char(25) NOT NULL, 
clname char(25) NOT NULL, 
aptnum int(100) NOT NULL,
street char(50) NOT NULL, 
pobox int(10) NOT NULL,
area char(50) NOT NULL, 
country char(50) NOT NULL, 
phone int(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (cid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Orderr
(
orderid int(8) NOT NULL, 
origin char(100) NOT NULL, 
destination char(100) NOT NULL, 
eta date NOT NULL, 
weight int(100) NOT NULL,
priority enum('F','R') NOT NULL,
task enum('P','D') NOT NULL, 
odate date NOT NULL, 
cnum int(12) NOT NULL, 
cpin int(8) NOT NULL,
custid int(7) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
FOREIGN KEY (custid) REFERENCES Customer(cid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE History 
(
histid int(6) NOT NULL, 
orderid int(8) NOT NULL, 
status enum('D','O','R') NOT NULL, 
current_loc char(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(histid), 
FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES Orderr(orderid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Driver
(
driverid int(6) NOT NULL,
dfname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
dlname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
dob date NOT NULL,
phone int(10) NOT NULL,
vehicle int(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (driverid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Vehicle
(
vid int(6) NOT NULL, 
num_plate varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
vtype enum(’T’,’B’,’P’) NOT NULL,
driverr int(6) NOT NULL,
orders int(8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (vid),
FOREIGN KEY (driverr) REFERENCES Driver(driverid),
FOREIGN KEY (orders) REFERENCES Orderr(orderid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Please, update your question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong single quotation marks for enum values, should be:

```
vtype enum('T','B','P') NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, I never noticed the quotes! :)